# Update bigquery dataset access from java

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a requirement where we need to give access to a particular user group in a bigquery dataset that contains views created by java code. I found that datasets.patch method can help me do it but not able to find documentation of what needs to be passed in the http request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the complete documentation on [how to update BigQuery dataset access controls](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-datasets#updating_dataset_access_controls) in the documentation page linked. Given that you are already creating the views in your dataset programatically, I would advise that you use the [BigQuery client library](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries), which may be more convenient than performing the API call to the [`datasets.patch` method](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets/patch). In any case, if you are still interested in calling the API directly, you should provide the relevant portions of a [dataset resource](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets#resource) in the body of the request.

The first link I shared provides a good example of [updating dataset access using the Java client libraries](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/3ebebd0b12c12d6a1c70db54c7f416ea0e70c2a1/google-cloud-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/bigquery/snippets/DatasetInfoSnippets.java#L43), but in short, this is what you should do:

```
public List<Acl> updateDatasetAccess(DatasetInfo dataset) {
    // Make a copy of the ACLs in order to modify them (adding the required group)
    List<Acl> previousACLs = dataset.getAcl();

    ArrayList<Acl> ACLs = new ArrayList<>(previousACLs);
    ACLs.add(Acl.of(new Acl.User("your_group@gmail.com"), Acl.Role.READER));

    DatasetInfo.Builder builder = dataset.toBuilder();
    builder.setAcl(ACLs);
    bigquery.update(builder.build());
}
```

---

***EDIT:***

The way to define the `dataset` object is the following one:

```
BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
Dataset dataset = bigquery.getDataset(DatasetId.of("YOUR_DATASET_NAME"));
```

Take into account that if you do not specify credentials when constructing the client object `bigquery`, the client library will look for credentials in the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for ypur response. I was trying the above mentioned steps beofre but the issue is the datasetinfo object always returns me null thats why i am not able to proceed with this.

                BigQuery bigQuery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
  DatasetId datasetId = DatasetId.of("fccr");
  DatasetInfo datasetInfo = Dataset.of(datasetId);

Comment: You might be instantianting your `dataset` object incorrectly. Please have a look at my edit and make sure that you are using the correct credentials and also specifying a valid dataset name in `DatasetId.of("YOUR_DATASET_NAME")`.

Comment: I am glad I could help! If the answer was useful for you, please consider [accepting and/or upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer so that the community sees it solved your issue. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @dsesto i have another query if you can help there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50820987/bigquery-iam-access-from-java

really sorry for troubling.